# The setenv command is not found when trying to run a shell script. How do I fix this?

Tags: scripts

I have a problem with a shell script, which looks like:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
setenv Test
```

The problem is that it worked until I installed Ubuntu 12.04.
The respond tells me that the command `setenv` is not found.

My idea is that the bash does not change to the csh but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the line

```
#!/bin/csh -f
```

is not the **very first** line in your script file. If it is the first line, then please post the exact error message that is being printed in terminal when you execute the script.

Please verify also that `csh`/`tcsh` is actually installed. You can do this by typing the following into terminal:

```
dpkg -l | grep csh
```

If this command produces no output at all, then you can install `tcsh` by entering following command:

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```